# Рыбный или рыбий жир?

Tags: употребление-слов

Наткнулся в сети на такую картинку, и, собственно, задумался: рыбные котлеты, рыбный фарш, но почему жир - рыбий?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вообще- то суффикс -ий  - это суффикс притяжательных прилагательных. Поэтому изначально рыбий, я думаю, притяжательное прилагательное, а рыбный - относительное. Что говорит словарь паронимов?

РЫБИЙ//РЫБНЫЙ
РЫБИЙ. 1. Относящийся к рыбе, принадлежащий ей. 2. перен. Бесстрастный, невыразительный, бесцветный, как у рыбы. Рыб|ий: 1) ~ий хвост; ~ья чешуя; ~ьи глаза, внутренности; 2) ~ьи глаза; ~ье выражение лица; ~ья натура.Посмотрели на крючок и увидели на нём рыбью губу. А.Чехов. Рыбья любовь. Классная дама, в тёмно-синем платье, со множеством перламутровых пуговиц на груди и с рыбьим холодным лицом, давно уже глядит на него издали тупым, ненавидящим взором мутных глаз. А.Куприн. Юнкера. Л Рыбья кровь (о холодном, равнодушном человеке). На рыбьем меху (о плохой верхней одежде, не предохраняющей от холода, не согревающей; шутл.).
РЫБНЫЙ. Связанный с разведением и добычей рыбы, с изготовлением из неё продукции, с покупкой и продажей рыбы; (разг.) пахнущий рыбой. Рыбн|ый: ~ое хозяйство, озеро; ~ые места; ~ый промысел; ~ая ловля; ~ое блюдо [еда]; ~ый суп; ~ые консервы; ~ый клей; ~ая мука; ~ый магазин; ~ая торговля, бочка; ~ый запах; ~ые руки; ~ая посуда. Я знал и этот монастырь, и это прекрасное, глубокое рыбное озеро! М.Салтыков-Щедрин. Благонамеренные речи. "Таким - легко жить", - подумал он, слушая рассказ Дмитрия о поморах, о рыбном промысле. М.Горький. Жизнь Клима Самгина. Рыбные пироги не сходят со стола. И. Арамилев. В лесах Урала.

А вот этого я не знала. Оказывается, жир рыбий и рыбный - не одно и то же.

"Рыбий жир" или "Рыбный жир"?

Рыбий жир существует в двух формах, в зависимости от продукта, из которого он получен, - из печени или из мышц рыб. Тот рыбий жир, который большинству из нас хорошо знаком по не самым приятным детским воспоминаниям, является вытяжкой из печени рыб. Это источник витаминов А, Е, D. Они используются в педиатрии для профилактики рахита. Жир, получаемый из мышц рыб, среди специалистов известен как "рыбный жир". Это источник полиненасыщенных жирных кислот, комплекс которых получил название Омега-3.
"Второе пришествие" рыбьего жира как раз и связано с тем, что был открыт "рыбный жир". Сегодня он обретает все большую популярность.
При покупке обращайте внимание на то, из какого жира - печеночного или мышечного - изготовлен препарат. Такая информация должна содержаться на упаковке. Жир рыбьего тела на упаковке обозначают как "ихтиеновое" или "рыбье" масло.

Нашла [здесь](http://www.fishkamchatka.ru/?cont=long&id=17918&year=2009&today=20&month=07)

Comment: Ларf, а первая Ваша цитата (со словарной статьей) откуда? Мне сдается, она передает ситуацию вековой давности. Сейчас несколько сместились понятия, "рыбий" осталось в основном в устоявшихся выражениях и/или строго относящихся к одному экземпляру рыбы (рыбий плавник, рыбий пузырь).

Comment: Из словаря паронимов Вишняковой. Изд-во Русский язык, 1984 год. давненько, конечно. Но не сто лет назад. На "Грамоте" тоже этот словарь.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо.
Яне говорил, что источник старый, я в том смысле, что в нем информация неактуальная. Возможно - уже на момент издания неактуальная.
Это, повторяю, личное ощущение.

Answer (score 2):

Хороший вопрос.
"Рыбий жир" - традиция.

Сейчас у "рыбий" и "рыбный" несколько разные значения.
Рыбий - относится к одной отдельно взятой рыбе.
Рыбный - к существительному с собирательным значением, пищевому продукту.
Рыбий глаз, но рыбный день.

Поэтому сейчас бы сказали скорее "рыбный жир", что и реализовалось на этикетке. 
Но раньше, век-полтора назад, явного разделения значений не было (ну или граница шла как-то по-другому, тут не силен). Поэтому в литературе того времени чаще встречается "рыбий" во всех значениях, рыбный - преимущественно в контекстах, связанных с непосредственной добычей и реализацией рыбы (рыбная лавка, рыбный промысел).

Это и дало название пищевому и лекарственному продукту.

//=========================================

Ха! Однако не все так просто.

Раньше всем детям давали рыбий жир. Потом в нём якобы нашли что-то нехорошее, и он исчез. А теперь в аптеках появился РЫБНЫЙ жир. Чем он отличается от рыбьего?

К. Б а т о в а, Калуга

Отвечает Ирина Захарова, профессор, завкафедрой педиатрии Российской медицинской академии последипломного образования:

- Рыбий жир, вкус которого нам знаком с детства, - вытяжка из печени рыб. Раньше его действительно рекомендовали всем детям в качестве общеукрепляющего и иммуностимулирующего средства. Потом были проведены исследования, которые показали, что употребление такого жира в больших количествах может негативно сказываться на печени и почках. Поэтому рыбный жир, который появился в продаже сравнительно недавно, добывают из мякоти рыб, прилегающей к мышечной ткани, что избавляет его от недостатков предшественника.

http://www.aif.ru/health/dontknow/1697

Т.е. тут претензия на то, что это ***разные*** продукты. 
Впрочем, к орфоэпии и грамматике это отношения не имеет - и ничего из ранее сказанного не отменяет.

Comment: Пока писала ответ, Вы тоже нашли подобную информацию. А я сначала сомневалась в источнике.

Comment: А я и сейчас в нем сомневаюсь. Но это не повод, чтобы её не привести тут.

Comment: Надо же! Спасибо большое за разъяснения! Я не знала о таком.